Concurrency MainActor Crash: root.user-initiated-qos.cooperative
The following code (simplified for brevity) causes a crash:
Crashed: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos.cooperative
@Published var thing: Thing?

func start() {
    Task { @MainActor in await getThing() }
}

func getThing() async {
    self.thing = await foo.fetchThing()
}

From my understanding, assigning self.thing is done safely since it's caller is assigned to the main actor (and thereby inherited). What is wrong here?

Please show a [mcve]. I should not need to make any assumptions regarding how you are calling start, what fetchThing does, and what foo is, etc.

So it is not discernable with the code above is what you're saying.

Well, I can make guesses (e.g. you are assigning self.thing off the main actor), but I cannot reproduce the crash with basic assumptions. The crash could be caused by something else, for all I know.

It's a threading issue and the crash is happening sparsely, so trying to create a minimum reproducible example seems impossible. Hence why it seemed more appropriate to err on the side of conceptual to understand any blatant issues

Assuming this is in a type not isolated to the main actor, then getThing will be run on a cooperative thread pool thread. You should get an error message saying that you are publishing changes on a background thread too.

Unlike GCD, in Swift concurrency, the actor isolation of getThing is dictated by how getThing was declared, not by the actor isolation from where it was called. The fact that you called it from a task isolated to the main actor is immaterial. If you want getThing to run on the main actor, you have a few choices:

Isolate getThing to the main actor:
class Bar: ObservableObject {
    @Published var thing: Thing?

    private let foo = Foo()

    func start() {
        Task { await getThing() }
    }

    @MainActor
    func getThing() async {
        self.thing = await foo.fetchThing()
    }
}

This pattern is a little brittle, because the burden rests on your shoulders to ensure that any methods that mutate thing are explicitly isolated to the main actor. You could minimize that sort of thing by isolating thing to the main actor, too:
class Baz: ObservableObject {
    @MainActor
    @Published var thing: Thing?

    private let foo = Foo()

    func start() {
        Task { await getThing() }
    }

    @MainActor
    func getThing() async {
        thing = await foo.fetchThing()
    }
}

By the way, if you change the “Strict concurrency checking” build setting to “Complete” (or use Swift 6), the compiler will warn you about the thread-safety issues in the first example.

Alternatively, you would isolate the whole class to the main actor which would effectively isolate thing and getThing to the main actor for you:
@MainActor
class Bar: ObservableObject {
    @Published var thing: Thing?

    private let foo = Foo()

    func start() {
        Task { await getThing() }
    }

    func getThing() async {
        self.thing = await foo.fetchThing()
    }
}

This latter pattern is recommended in the conclusion of the Discover concurrency in SwiftUI video (and more details are provided earlier in that video).

As an aside, depending upon your minimum OS version, especially if this was a SwiftUI app, you might consider using the newer Observation framework:
import Observation

@Observable
@MainActor
class Baz {
    var thing: Thing?

    private let foo = Foo()

    func start() {
        Task { await getThing() }
    }

    func getThing() async {
        thing = await foo.fetchThing()
    }
}

Note, the Observation framework eliminates the SwiftUI problem with background updates from another actor, but you need to still solve the thread-safety issues within this type, so a global actor (such as the main actor) is still prudent.
For more information on the Observation framework, see Discover Observation in SwiftUI.



Gotcha. So essentially the task marked @MainActor does nothing in this one line case because it immediately defers to any old thread due to the await. It sounds like a two-fold problem, where isolating the method getThing() as @MainActor enforces the setting of the property to the main actor (in this snippet only), but does nothing to ensure thread safety around the mutating/getting of said property elsewhere, hence the option to isolate the entire class to @MainActor. Am I understanding that correctly?

FWIW, I might not say that it “defers to any old thread”. The Task { @MainActor in … }, itself, runs on the main actor, but the thread used by getThing is dictated by whether that function is actor-isolated or not. FWIW, an async function that is not actor-isolated will run on the “generic executor” (i.e., it will not run on the main thread, but will run on a thread from the cooperative thread pool, not isolated to any actor). But, your summary is generally correct.

Doesn't the recommendation of Observation rely on an assumption that the OP is operating within SwiftUI? I don't see any evidence that that's the case.

Technically, no, the Observation framework does not require SwiftUI; but, in practice, yes, its usage in UIKit/AppKit is so cumbersome that one would generally only use it from SwiftUI (which is why I included a “Observation in SwiftUI” video.) But I’ve added an additional SwiftUI qualifier to this third point.
